# How about this universal http calling method using Dio?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio, dart3

I'm developing with `flutter3` and `dio`, and I'm fed up with writing many methods to make requests for different API, so I tried to write a general calling method:

```dart
Future<T> call<T>(
  HttpEndpoint endpoint,
  T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromJson,
) async {
  final response = await dio.request(
    endpoint.path,
    data: endpoint.body,
    options: Options(method: endpoint.method),
  );
  return fromJson(response.data);
}

HttpEndpoint({
  required this.path,
  required this.method,
  this.body = const {},
});
```

After my test, this method can work normally, but I have some questions.

1. Is there any performance problem or other problem with this writing?
2. When I have the definition of HttpEndpoint encapsulation API, I hope there is a general http calling method. What is the popular writing method in the industry?
3. It seems that the generic T in front of the fromJson parameter can be deleted. What is its function?

If there is anything confusing in my description, please feel free to point it out and I will correct it in time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the most "popular" method in the industry. but I tried **Dio** on some of my projects but some limitations on the library made me replace it completely with regular **http** requests.

One of the most common bugs I found was that some header values on my requests were overwritten by the library.

Because of that I dropped dio and now I only use **Dart http** library.
This is what you need to use it:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

And then to call the service there are several alternatives, depending on what you need to send.

This is a regular **http GET**:

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

Instead of get you have other methods like **post**, **put** etc...

If you need to add custom **Headers** to your **request**, you can create a **Request** object, and change or add all the properties you need. Here is another example:

```
var req = http.Request('GET',Uri.parse(url));
// set headers
req.headers.addAll({
    "content-type": "application/json",
    // other headers you might need 
});
```

If you need to send information in the request **body/data**, this is how you do it:

```
req.body = """{"jsonrpc": 2.0, "params":{}}""";
// The body string can be whatever you need ...
// this is just an example
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I used to use the `http` framework.

But I found that it seems inconvenient to write interceptors, and the API can't be defined visually by using URI, so I used `Dio` to refactor the code.

Comment: @AllinProgram I only see one more reason to try it. I don't understand why you say it's inconvenient to write **interceptors**, which are literally just **callbacks**. It's a learning opportunity and a way for you to know better your code and the connection behavior.